# Exporting nested list items

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, export-to-excel

I have a program that automatically generates a 2D grid of buttons and stores the grid in a nested list and I am trying to export this list to MS Excel. however the code that I am trying throws to many errors. I can get this working without using a list but I need to use a nested list in order to clear the list a populate it again if and when the size of the grid increases or decreases. Is the logic that I'm using even doable

As follows:

```
        //This is not the complete code
        List<List<Button>> buttonss = new List<List<Button>>();
        List<Button> rowList = new List<Button>();

        //Some method that creates a grid of buttons 
        buttons = new Button[row][];
        for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
        { 
            buttons[r] = new Button[col];
            buttonss.Add(rowList);    
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
            {
                buttons[r][c] = new Button();
                rowList.Add(buttons[r][c]);
            }
        }
```

The next thing that I want to do is ot export this list into excel.

The grid:
[image]

Button:

```
//Export to MS Excel button
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ep.Do("sheet.xsl", rowList);//(ERROR 0)
}
```

Class:

```
//Export class
public void Do(string excelName, System.Collections.Generic.List<Button[][]> Grid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Grid.Count(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= Grid[i].Count(); j++)
        {

            AddData(i, j, Grid[i][j]);//(ERROR HERE [1])

        }
    }
    //app.SaveWorkspace(excelName);
}

public void AddData(int row, int col, System.Collections.Generic.List<Button[][]> button)
{
    if (button == null) return;
    row++;
    col++;

    Range range = worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 2];
    if (!defaultBackgroundIsWhite)
    {
        range.Interior.Color = button.BackColor.ToArgb();//(ERROR HERE[2])
    }
    else
        range.Interior.Color = button.BackColor.Name != "Control" ? button.BackColor.ToArgb() : System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb();//(ERROR HERE)
    // range.NumberFormat = "";
    worksheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 2] = button.Text;//(ERROR HERE[3])
    row--;
    col--;
}
```

Errors:
0:Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'    C:..

1:The best overloaded method match for 'SmartRota.ExportHeadWaiter.AddData(int, int, System.Collections.Generic.List)' has some invalid arguments    C:..

2:Error 3   'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'BackColor' and no extension method 'BackColor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:..

3: Same eroor as above

Answer (score 2):

Well there is quite a few problems with your code, mostly the `Type` of the parameters your functions receive.

For instance:
1 . `rowList` is a `List<Button>` and you're passing it to the function `Do()` yet, the function Do expects a `List<Button[][]>`

2 . To make things worse, `AddData` expects to receive an array of Buttons yet the entire code inside `AddData` considers you having *only one button* and *not* an array.

3 . Calling `ToArgb()` return as int, yet you're trying to put it in a `Color`

Without trying to really understand *what* you're trying to do, I'm guessing this is how you want to declare your functions:

```
public void Do(string excelName, System.Collections.Generic.List<Button[]> Grid)
```

and:

```
public void AddData(int row, int col, Button button)
```

Comment: Any idea how I can sort this out

Comment: Well start by correctly declaring your functions' parameters. Then try to understand why you're trying to Pass a `List<Button>` to the `Do` function which should probably expect a `List<Button[]>` (based on your supplied code).

Comment: I corrected that but its say that AddData(i, j, hwGrid[i][j]); and ep.Do("sheet.xsl", rowList); has some invalid arguments

Comment: About AddData, it shouldn't write that if you what I told you. About Do(..., rowList) - just as I said, you're passing a List<Button> instead of a List<Button[]>

Comment: Do you mean I need to make rowlist into an array

Comment: Maybe,  _you_ need to understand what you plan on passing to the function. I didn't write this code - you did. If you're still not sure what these functions do and what parameters they expect I suggest you stop, read the code, understand it and _only then_ continue writing your program.

Comment: That,s true! I'm finding it challenging I guess i just have to keep trying thanks for your help much appreciated